# Deep Reinforcement Learning (Python - Keras) - Reduce a Probability Observation

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

### Goal

I have a program that returns a float value between 0 and 1 based on a given state. I am attempting to implement a Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithm that will take actions to find a state that reduces the returned value.

### Results

The program has been run over steps and episodes, where each step gets an observation probability and then at the beginning of the next episode the starting state is reset. Averaging out the steps over the episodes, typically there is a dip in the probability and then it starts rising until it is at least higher than where it started, where I was hoping it would just lower the probability until the episode ended. Looking closer, there are episodes where it seems like the value is maximized all the way to 1, while there are other episodes where the value gets as low as ~0.015. Each episode is reset to values that begin somewhere around 0.6. The episodes where the highs and lows seemed to be interspersed throughout the entire run, without a pattern that I've been able to recognize. I've included a graph of the average of an
[Example Run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apw2o.png) (I guess I don't have permissions to actually include the graphic outside of a link, apologies.)

### Code

The code below is the reward segment of what I have so far. I modified the DQN tutorial from [Sentdex](https://pythonprogramming.net/q-learning-algorithm-reinforcement-learning-python-tutorial/?completed=/q-learning-reinforcement-learning-python-tutorial/). I've provided few sections of my modified code related to rewards below.

I began by modifying the reward to be given out when the target or less probability is achieved. Then I realized that the reward and penalty could be modified by the probability to give the DRL even more incentive. And that's the build that got the above results.

### Troubleshooting

I've also tried modifying the training module to be `new_q = reward + DISCOUNT * (1-max_future_q)`
, `current_qs = (1.0-current_qs_list[index])`, `max_future_q = (1.0-np.max(future_qs_list[index]))`
and `max_future_q = np.min(future_qs_list[index])`. If I understand correctly all I did with these was mess up the rewards calculation for the DRL, not cause the DRL to be better rewarded for lowering the probability which is what I was trying to do.

Is there something here that is rewarding the increased probability, or is there something else I'm missing that might be giving me the results I'm seeing and maybe I should change my expectations?

```
    class Env:
        MOVE_PENALTY = 1
        REWARD = 10000
        self.target = 0.5
        
        def step(self, action):
            self.episode_step += 1
            self.player.action(action)
            
            return self.find_reward()
        
        
        def find_reward(self):
            self.observe()
            if self.prob <= self.target:
                reward = self.REWARD *(1.0-self.prob)
            else:
                reward = -self.MOVE_PENALTY * self.prob
            
            
    class Agent:
    
        def create_model(self):
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=STATE_SIZE, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(ACTION_SIZE, activation='linear'))
            model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))
            
            return model
    
        def train(self, terminal_state, step):
    
    
            current_states = np.array([transition[0] for transition in minibatch])
            current_qs_list = self.model.predict(current_states)
            
    
            new_current_states = np.array([transition[3] for transition in minibatch])
            future_qs_list = self.target_model.predict(new_current_states)
    
    
            for index, (current_state, action, reward, new_current_state, done) in enumerate(minibatch):
                if not done:
                    max_future_q = np.max(future_qs_list[index])
                    new_q = reward + DISCOUNT * max_future_q
                else:
                    new_q = reward
                current_qs = current_qs_list[index]
                current_qs[action] = new_q
    
                X.append(current_state)
                y.append(current_qs)
    
            self.model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y), batch_size=MINIBATCH_SIZE, verbose = 0, shuffle=False, callbacks=None)
            
    for episode in tqdm(range(1, EPISODES+1), ascii=True, unit="episode"):
    
        while not done:
            if np.random.random() > epsilon:
                action = np.argmax(agent.get_qs(current_state))
            else:
                action = np.random.randint(0, env.ACTION_SPACE_SIZE)
            
            new_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
            
            episode_reward += reward
            
            agent.update_replay_memory((current_state, action, reward, new_state, done))
            agent.train(done, step)
            current_state = new_state
            step += 1
```